# Get Search Location from Index Page & Zoom to Location on Map Page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to setup a redirect from the index page to the map page, so if a user searches for an address using the Places Autocomplete library, they get redirected to the map page with the location that they searched for. The index page does not include a map, but just the search bar with Places Autocomplete library.

The function I've setup on the index page is as follows:

```
var place;
function indexSearch() {
    // Get Address Field and Attach Places Autocomplete
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Get Place When Place_Changed Event if Fired
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (typeof place !== 'undefined') {
            window.location.href = 'map';
            // Don't know what to do here
            // as I can't use map.panTo(place.geometry.location) because
            // map does not exist on index page.
        }
    });

    // Erase Previous Address if Search Bar is Clicked
    inputIndex.onclick = function () {
        inputIndex.value = '';
    } 
}
```

Do I need to include something in the `initialize()` function which is responsible for setting up the map?

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: {
            lat: -33.8666,
            lng: 151.1958
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    // Catch place and pan map to its location
}
```

**Edit**: At least provide a reason for downvote.

I'm looking into using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Pass the lat and lng to either of those, and retrieve the location when the map page is loading. Is this an optimal solution? Will update with answer once I have the solution.

Comment: I had used solution with `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` before with your situation, and I think that's the best way, bro. Try this ^^

Comment: Thank you. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. It's working for me. Hope it helps someone in future.

In `indexSearch()` function, set a key in `sessionStorage` to store lat and lng of place that is searched. Capture this information when the `place_event` is fired.

```
var place;
function indexSearch() {
    // Get Address Field and Attach Places Autocomplete
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Get Place When Place_Changed Event if Fired
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (typeof place !== 'undefined') {
            window.location.href = 'map';
            // Set key in sessionStorage
            sessionStorage.myLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            sessionStorage.myLat = place.geometry.location.lng();
        }
    });

    // Erase Previous Address if Search Bar is Clicked
    inputIndex.onclick = function () {
        inputIndex.value = '';
    } 
}
```

Then in `initialize()` function, check to see if the key exists. If it does, take the user to that location.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: {
            lat: -33.8666,
            lng: 151.1958
        },
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // Get place from sessionStorage if its exists & pan map to its location
    var placeLat = sessionStorage.getItem('myLat');
    var placeLng = sessionStorage.getItem('myLng');
    if (placeLat && placeLng) {
         var searchedPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(placeLat, placeLng);
         map.setCenter(searchedPlace);
         map.setZoom(15);
    }
}
```